# FAB not positioning inside CoordinatorLayout with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I am trying to display a list of items with a FAB to add a new item. The current screen is as below.

[image]

I have a CoordinatorLayout which has only a RecyclerView and the FAB. My problem is the FAB is not getting anchored to the bottom of the page, but to the bottom of the RecyclerView whose height seems to behave as if its `wrap_content`, but I've declared as `match_parent`. The RecylerView has a silver background for illustrative purposes.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ae.apps.tripmeter.fragments.expenses.TripsListFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/silver"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_trip"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:elevation="8dp"/>
```

I can't figure out why I am not able to position the FAB at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Can you show the whole xml?

Comment: Seems you are using features of `RelativeLayout` but there is none inside your code. Try to put `RelativeLayout` with `match_parent` in width and height below your `CoordinatorLayout` but as parent to the `RecyclerView` and `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: @kara4k, this is the entire xml file

Comment: If this is your entire xml file, where does the `ToolBar`come from?

Comment: Toolbar is in the parent Activity. This content is a Fragment.

Comment: That is very important information! **Please, look at my edited answer below.** The FAB must be in the Parent Activity in order for it to be at the bottom of your activity. Putting the FAB in the Fragment forces it to remain with the Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for that catch. Actually I have many fragments that are loaded in same Activity, but only 1 requires the FAB and the click functionality of that is also specific to that Fragment. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would need to know more about the code you are using to handle the `onClick` event when the FAB is tapped. But, my initial response would be that if you need only one FAB for the complete `Activity` keep the FAB in the Parent Activity and handle the `onClick` as you would, normally. **Do you need the FAB to appear and disappear in response to user interaction?**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I need the FAB only when 1 Fragment is loaded and be hidden when other fragments are shown. My app is located at https://github.com/midhunhk/trip-o-meter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting the `RecyclerView` in a 'content' layout file and add it to the main layout via

```
<include layout="@layout/content_recyclerview" />
```

---

**EDIT:**

The FAB should not be placed in the Fragment if it is to reside at the bottom of the `Activity`. Remove the FAB from the fragment and add it to the main activity. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.your_company.your_project">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <-- ref. your recycler here -->
    <include layout="@layout/content_with_your_list"/>

    <-- Put the FAB here -->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now in your fragment remove the FAB! It should reside in your main activity with the `CoordinateLayout`. Use a simple `LinearLayout` in your fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              tools:showIn="@layout/activity_your_main_activity"
              >


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/silver"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

You will need to make changes were appropriate in order to fit you your project.

---

**Toggle FAB visibility**

In order to toggle the visibility of the FAB add the following property to the `FloatingActionButton` in your Parent Activity.

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

and make it visible in code with:

```
mFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

or invisible, again with

```
mFab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Whenever you need, eg. when a fragment is displayed or removed.

Comment: Please leave an explanation when you down vote. Otherwise I will not be able to improve my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I think CoordinatorLayout has to be the root layout for the expected behavior of the FAB

Comment: Yes, your are correct. The behavior of the FAB is not as expected when nested in a `LinearLayout`. I have edited that out of my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcIiZ.png)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"/>
```

If you want to have some layout under fab, you should use relative layout as root layout. And put my code in this relative layout.

Comment: How exactly is this xml different from what is in the question?

Comment: I want to achieve this layout, but seems like this is the how I presently have the layout in my question.

Comment: But I have fab on bottom of screen and you not. So It can´t be same.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to anchor the fab at bottom of the recyclerView and it gives me my desired output. Try with this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_margin="16sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So should I use RelativeLayout instead of the CoordinatorLayout

Comment: yes....Even with coordinateLayout it works...If you want to use Coordinate Layout use       `android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"`      in `FAB` 
 and remove the following line   
  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" `     ...it will give you what you want...and also if you use RelativeLayout,my answer will give you what you want.So basically you can use either of them
`